# Magento2 How to Compress CSS & JS

Tags: magento2

I checked My website in Gtmetrix it is asking to Compress CSS & Js files.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Login to the admin panel and go to **stores > configuration > advanced > developer > javascript settings > minify javascript files** and set it to yes.

For CSS do the same with **stores > configuration > advanced > developer > CSS settings > minify css files**

Comment: Set it to No or Yes

Comment: please set is yes

Comment: I meant set it to yes sorry, I will update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Just log into your Magento admin panel and navigate to **Store > Configuration > Advanced**  and expand the **JavaScript Settings** section.

[image]

Uncheck the system value of Merge JavaScript Files, Enable JavaScript Bundling, and Minify JavaScript Files. Then change it to YES.

Staying on the same page expand the CSS setting and change the status to YES.

[image]

Comment: I did all of this still gtmetrix is asking for compressing files of CSS & Js

Comment: Did you clear the cache after executing all these processes?

Or

Try this, navigate to env.php, and switch to developer mode. Then, perform all the above processes.

At last, run this command: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Before, did you check all the JS and CSS files got compress? You can check it by inspecting your page and in the network section use the filer to search for the JS and CSS files.